# Is it a bad idea to edit a rig after it has been reposed?

Tags: rigging

Like the title asks, is it a bad idea to edit a rig after it has been reposed in the pose position?

It seems that doing so causes nothing but problems.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell from your question but you might want to **apply pose as rest pose** before you go on and edit your rig.

Comment: I guess that means YES, it is a bad idea. 

My question regards the proper procedure for dealing with a rigged object. It appears from the way Blender works that if any changes are made to the object in rest position, they will affect every pose that was created prior to that change.

Comment: It's not a bad idea per se, it's actually quite flexible compared to other things like shape keys. But I guess it depends on what exactly you want. If you've already animated everything only to afterwards find out that your rig and model need major reworking, then your workflow is probably flawed. Poses (usually?) are relative to the rest pose, thus making changes to the rest pose affects other poses as well...